# `object` supplied to `ReactiveComponent`, expected `function`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactivesearch

I'm getting this error when trying to use ReactiveSearch for a search bar. This is how I'm initialising it:

```
render() {
    const { tenantConfig, size, componentId } = this.props;
    return (
      <ReactiveComponent
        componentId={componentId}
        defaultQuery={this.defaultQuery}
      >
        <SearchDropdownDashboard
          size={size}
          handleSearchDashboard={this.handleSearchDashboard}
          fetching={this.state.fetching}
          tenantConfig={tenantConfig}
        />
      </ReactiveComponent>
    );
  }
```

And this is the function that is being passed in:

```
defaultQuery = () => {
    const { dashboardText } = this.state;
    const { mustNotObj } = this.props;

    let obj;

    obj = {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must_not: mustNotObj,
          must: multiMatchSearch(dashboardText)
        }
      },
      from: 0,
      size: 20
    };

    return obj;
  };
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here? The function seems to be passed correctly to the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `v3`, then it is due to the recent changes introduced in API. You will need to use `render` prop or React render Pattern as done in the below example.

You can check the docs here: https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/reactivecomponent.html#usage-with-defaultquery.

I have created the example of Usage of ReactiveComponent on both the versions:

`v3` : https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-ritchie-rjo3m

`v2` : https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-ramanujan-f3g31

Hope this helps!

Comment: Some modifications but ty, that helped